# How do I change the date according to the length of the string?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['20201010', '200910', '2015','20']})
df['date'] = np.where(df.date.str.len() == 8, #format = '%Y%m%d',
                      np.where(df.date.str.len() == 6, #format = '%y%m%d'
                               np.where(df.date.str.len() == 4, #format = '%Y',None
```

I don't know how to write the code. I want to make it like this.

```
 df['text']                df['date']

20201010        =>     2020-10-10 00:00:00
200910          =>     2020-09-10 00:00:00
2015            =>     2015-01-01 00:00:00
20              =>     None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion here is not necessary test length, you can test formats with `errors='coerce'` for missing values if failed, last combine formats by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) or [`Series.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
f1 = pd.to_datetime(df['text'], format = '%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')                     
f2 = pd.to_datetime(df['text'], format = '%y%m%d', errors='coerce')
f3 = pd.to_datetime(df['text'], format = '%Y', errors='coerce')

df['date'] = f1.fillna(f2).fillna(f3)
#alternative
#df['date'] = f1.combine_first(f2).combine_first(f3)
print (df)
       text       date
0  20201010 2020-10-10
1    200910 2020-09-10
2      2015 2020-01-05
3        20        NaT
```